# Head First Design Patterns: Decorator behavior puzzling

Tags: java, design-patterns

This is a question on the behavior of the code rather then the pattern itself. I will lay out the code below

```
  public abstract class Beverage {
    protected String description;

    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }
    public abstract BigDecimal cost();
}


public abstract class CondimentDecorator extends Beverage{
    @Override
    public abstract String getDescription();
}

public class HouseBlend extends Beverage{

    public HouseBlend() {
        description = "House Blend";
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal cost() {
        return BigDecimal.valueOf(.89);
    }

}

public class Mocha extends CondimentDecorator{
    Beverage beverage;

    public Mocha(Beverage beverage) {
        this.beverage = beverage;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        System.out.println("desc: " + beverage.getDescription());
        return beverage.getDescription() + ", Mocha";
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal cost() {
        System.out.println("bev: "+beverage.cost());
        return BigDecimal.valueOf(.20).add(beverage.cost());
    }

}

public class CoffeeTest {
        public static void main(String args[]){
            Beverage blend = new HouseBlend();
            blend = new Mocha(blend);
            blend = new Mocha(blend);
            blend = new Mocha(blend);
            System.out.println(blend.getDescription() + " * "+blend.cost());
        }
}
```

When CoffeeTest is run I get the following output which I would like to understand

```
1    desc: House Blend
2    desc: House Blend, Mocha
3    desc: House Blend
4    desc: House Blend, Mocha, Mocha
5    desc: House Blend
6    desc: House Blend, Mocha
7    desc: House Blend
8    bev: 0.89
9    bev: 1.09
10    bev: 0.89
11    bev: 1.29
12    bev: 0.89
13    bev: 1.09
14    bev: 0.89
15    House Blend, Mocha, Mocha, Mocha * 1.49
```

So these are my questions:

1. I expected 'desc' and 'bev' to be printed 3x, so why the xtra lines?
2. How is 'House Blend, Mocha, Mocha' printed when there is no explicit state saved?
3. I have the same question about 'cost', how is `beverage.cost()` saving state by adding the amounts.

I am sure the answers lie in polymorphism between Beverage and CondimentDecorator.

Comment: I don't see decorator pattern usage here

Comment: why not? this is docoration: Beverage blend = new HouseBlend(); blend = new Mocha(blend); blend = new Mocha(blend);

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project?

Comment: Unless you've edited the code, you won't get the output you give above.

With the code as it is right now, there are exactly three lines of output: 1) "desc: HouseBlend";  2) "bev: 0.89", and 3) "HouseBlend, Mocha * 1.09".  

Not 15 lines, three.

Comment: Now that you've changed your code to match your output, the expected behavior is obvious and matches what's seen, so I'm assuming you consider your question answered by one of the answerers below..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is 'House Blend, Mocha, Mocha' printed when there is no explicit state saved?

You are creating 3 distinct objects. Let us call them a, b and c. So we can rewrite the code to look like this:

```
Beverage a = new HouseBlend();
Beverage b = new Mocha(a);
Beverage c = new Mocha(b);
System.out.println(c.getDescription() + " * "+c.cost());
```

which will do the same thing as your code but it is clearer that you are dealing with 3 different objects. Assigning

```
blend = new Mocha(blend);
```

does not replace the object but actually creates a new object and simply modifies the reference blend to the new object.

When you call blend.getDescription() in your code you are referring to object c, which calls getDescription of object b which calls getDescription of object a. The getDescription() of object a returns the String "House Blend". So, getDescription() of object b returns "House Blend, Mocha". And getDescription() of object c then returns "House Blend, Mocha, Mocha".

A very similar thing happens to getCost().

Answer (score 0):

in Mocha.getDescription you have System.out.println and addiotionally you return something, that you print also in the void main. but nevertheless I get the following:
desc: House Blend
desc: House Blend, Mocha
desc: House Blend
bev: 0.89
bev: 1.09
bev: 0.89
House Blend, Mocha, Mocha * 1.29
if in void main you have three times new Mocha the output looks like yours

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Beverage blend = new HouseBlend();
        blend = new Mocha(blend);
        blend = new Mocha(blend);
        blend = new Mocha(blend);
        System.out.println(blend.getDescription() + " * "+blend.cost());
}
```

decorator pattern works like wrapping objects around objects here it is like:
HouseBlend has_a ( Mocha has_a ( Mocha has_a ( Mocha ) ) )

Answer (score 0):

In getDescription, you call beverage.getDescription() twice, both of which print lines.